# Check Uniqueness, Skip and Enter Data Accordingly in Django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a condition where i am taking data from google place api. In my model `place_id` is `unique` field. I have created api where it takes multiple data - somewhat like this - `[{},{},{}]`.

When i enter data with 2 same `place_id` it gives error - `"masjid with this place id already exists."`.

Instead of that unique error of `place_id`. I want to check if `place_id` already exists then don't give error, just skip it and enter those data which are having unique `place_id`.

Here i will give you an example where i have send data using `json`.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jama masjid",
        "address": "XYZ",
        "latitude": 25454.25,
        "longitude": 1541.4,
        "place_id": "place_id" <---- This place_id already exist in database
    },
    {
        "name": "Noor masjid",
        "address": "kondhwa",
        "latitude": 25454.25,
        "longitude": 1541.4,
        "place_id": "place_id1"
    }
]
```

So in Response it produce this error -

```
[
    {
        "place_id": [
            "masjid with this place id already exists."
        ]
    },
    {}
]
```

**Note - I am sending multiple data - `many=True`**

Models.py

```
class Masjid(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
class MasjidAddGoogleAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Masjid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MasjidAddGoogleSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = serializers.MasjidAddGoogleSerialzer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        print(data)
        if isinstance(data, list):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serilizers.py

```
class MasjidAddGoogleSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Masjid
        fields = [
            'name',
            'address',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
            'place_id'
        ]
```

Comment: i think you can use `for` in `request.data` and save one by one like dont have `many=True`

Comment: Yeah i tried to do same and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have iterated over the list which is been send. Then i matched the field `place_id` with database and created new `list`. According to that new `list` data was entered in database.

New list create -

```
data_final = [i for i in data if not (Masjid.objects.filter(place_id=i['place_id']).exists() == True)]
```

Views.py

```
class MasjidAddGoogleAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Masjid.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MasjidAddGoogleSerialzer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = serializers.MasjidAddGoogleSerialzer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data

        if data:   

            if isinstance(data, list):   

                data_final = [i for i in data if not (Masjid.objects.filter(place_id=i['place_id']).exists() == True)]        

                if data_final:
                    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data_final, many=True)

                    if serializer.is_valid():
                        serializer.save()
                        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

            else:
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

                if serializer.is_valid():
                        serializer.save()
                        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```